# Kivy: Moving mouse freeze main loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a video player application, with a graph display below it. My video player is fetching frames periodically, but when I move the mouse it freezes, and by printing what's happening I can see that the main loop didn't call anything

I've tried printing some text for every widget `on_mouse_pos` event but none of them is triggered, so I really don't know where should I look. Using the recorder module, I can see that there is no mouse event, so I'm not even sure the mouse event is recorder

I have several widgets now so I'm not sure posting them here would be useful, but I'd love to hear feeedback or any idea about this problem

Thanks a lot

Comment: Without seeing some code is hard to grasp you particular situation,

Comment: to get the mouse position through the whole window you do: Window.bind(mouse_pos=your_call_back_here)

Comment: Well I have several files now, and a dozen widgets, so I'm not sure what should I post. On top of that I've added a display on every on_mouse_pos of my widgets, but none of them is triggered when my mouse move, so I'm not really sure who's catching it ...

Comment: since you commented that you program is fetching frames constantly I have the feeling that the frame fetching loop might be interfering with kivy event loop, thus blocking the interface, when doing things that take a long time to respond or using loops you should use threads, and Clock events to avoid blocking the gui.

Comment: I use a queue system which is filled in a separate thread, and my widget is scheduled with the Clock module to periodically pull them. I however have doubts about wether I'm correctly using the @mainthread decorator

Comment: And using the monitor or recorder tool, there is no trace of those mouse events, which troubles me

Comment: well as far as I understand the @mainthread decorator is used when you are inside a thread and you call a method that updates any of the widgets, the method that updates any widget attribute must be in the same thread as the gui's main thread, hence the use of mainthread decorator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this, my frame pulling function was in a separate thread, moving it to a periodically triggered Clock event fixed this.
I'm still not sure why this bug happened, my 2 cents is that opencv block the GIL while reading a frame, and this somehow interfered with how kivy manages its events

Comment: Yep, can't do it till tomorrow though